# Formula to convert from WGS 84 / UTM Zone 34N to WGS 84?

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon-creation

Can anyone help me with the formula for converting from WGS 84 / UTM Zone 34N to World Geodetic System?

My problem is I want to represent some properties (polygons) in some kind of a map (image). I have the data stored in SQL Server (the points of the polygon). The SQL Server uses WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N to represent the polygons. My development environment uses a simple XY system. I want to convert these data in latitude and longitude so that I can draw a simple map in my program.

So far I have found a converter online: http://georepository.com/calculator/convert/crs_a/4326/crs_b/32634/operation_id/16034

However I would like to know the formula for doing this, since I want to use it in my code. Some samples are:

```
 Easting (Metre): 398676.179117283 ----> longitude : 19° 47' 20.659" E
Northing (Metre): 4576702.45725602 ----> latitude  : 41° 20'  7.586" N
```

---

Maybe I am being unclear. However, let's say that all I want is to convert from UTM to GCS WGS84. Can anyone help me with a formula?

In other words I want to do what the converter I does.

Comment: What has your research turned up so far? How far have you gotten? Where are you stuck? (**edit** the question to improve its quality)

Comment: I think you're missing some of the definition of coordinate systems here (or I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do). Lat/long, or GCS WGS84, are spherical/ellipsoidal coordinates - ie, not 'simple xy'. The UTM zone is a projected coordinate system, which *is* 'simple xy'. So if you want to draw something based on a flat Cartesian coordinate system you want the UTM values, not lat/long. The term you're looking for to go from spherical to 2D Cartesian is *projection* (and going the other way as you want, unprojecting).

Comment: Formulas at [UTM Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#From_UTM_coordinates_.28E.2C_N.2C_Zone.2C_Hemi.29_to_latitude.2C_longitude_.28.CF.86.2C_.CE.BB.29) (no idea if they're correct).

Comment: what formula can I calculate with it the distance between two points have longitude & latitude ,with Excel in windows .
thank you very much

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100017)

Answer (score 8):

The website in @Ahmed GIS's answer is no longer available [at the original URL](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM/), but you can still have a look [on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221085505/http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM/).

The JavaScript is inlined in the page source, as Ahmed mentions.

Since all you need is Zone 34N, you can simplify that a lot by inlining some of the constants, but to make this answer more generic, here is a complete solution that works with any reference system.

I cleaned up the JavaScript a little since the language has evolved a lot since the original code was written, but the idea is still the same.

Note that this example will give you the coordinates in decimal (which is what most things accept anyways), but you can convert them to degrees/minutes/seconds quite easily (look near the end of the original function).

```js
// Constants.
// Symbols as used in USGS PP 1395: Map Projections - A Working Manual
const DatumEqRad = [6378137.0,
                    6378137.0,
                    6378137.0,
                    6378135.0,
                    6378160.0,
                    6378245.0,
                    6378206.4,
                    6378388.0,
                    6378388.0,
                    6378249.1,
                    6378206.4,
                    6377563.4,
                    6377397.2,
                    6377276.3]; 
const DatumFlat = [298.2572236,
                   298.2572236,
                   298.2572215,
                   298.2597208,
                   298.2497323,
                   298.2997381,
                   294.9786982,
                   296.9993621,
                   296.9993621,
                   293.4660167,
                   294.9786982,
                   299.3247788,
                   299.1527052,
                   300.8021499]; 

const Item = 0;                    // default
const a    = DatumEqRad[Item];     // equatorial radius (meters)
const f    = 1 / DatumFlat[Item];  // polar flattening
const drad = Math.PI / 180;        // convert degrees to radians

// Mor constants, extracted from the function:
const k0   = 0.9996;                      // scale on central meridian
const b    = a*(1 - f);                   // polar axis
const e    = Math.sqrt(1 - (b/a)*(b/a));  // eccentricity
const e0   = e / Math.sqrt(1 - e*e);      // called e' in reference
const esq  = (1 - (b/a) * (b/a));         // e² for use in expansions
const e0sq = e*e / (1 - e*e);             // e0² — always even powers

function utmToLatLon(x, y, utmz, north) {

  // First some validation:
  if (x < 160000 || x > 840000) {
    alert("Outside permissible range of easting values.");
    return;
  } 
  if (y < 0){
    alert("Negative values are not allowed for northing.");
    return;
  }
  if (y > 10000000) {
    alert("Northing may not exceed 10,000,000.");
    return;
  }

  // Now the actual calculation:
  const zcm = 3 + 6*(utmz-1) - 180;  // central meridian of zone
  const e1  = (1 - Math.sqrt(1 - e*e)) / (1 + Math.sqrt(1 - e*e));  // called e₁ in USGS PP 1395
  const M0  = 0;  // in case origin other than zero lat - not needed for standard UTM

  let M;  // arc length along standard meridian
  if (north) {
    M = M0 + y/k0;
  } else {  // southern hemisphere
    M = M0 + (y-10000000) / k;
  }
  const mu = M / (a * (1 - esq*(1/4 + esq*(3/64 + 5*esq/256))));
  let phi1 = mu + e1*(3/2 - 27*e1*e1/32)*Math.sin(2*mu) + e1*e1*(21/16 -55*e1*e1/32)*Math.sin(4*mu);  // footprint Latitude
  phi1 = phi1 + e1*e1*e1*(Math.sin(6*mu)*151/96 + e1*Math.sin(8*mu)*1097/512);
  const C1 = e0sq * Math.pow(Math.cos(phi1), 2);
  const T1 = Math.pow(Math.tan(phi1), 2);
  const N1 = a / Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(e * Math.sin(phi1), 2));
  const R1 = N1 * (1 - e*e) / (1 - Math.pow(e * Math.sin(phi1), 2));
  const D  = (x - 500000) / (N1*k0);
  let phi = (D*D) * (1/2 - D*D * (5 + 3*T1 + 10*C1 - 4*C1*C1 - 9*e0sq) / 24);
  phi = phi + Math.pow(D, 6) * (61 + 90*T1 + 298*C1 + 45*T1*T1 -252*e0sq - 3*C1*C1) / 720;
  phi = phi1 - (N1 * Math.tan(phi1) / R1) * phi;

  // Output Latitude:
  const outLat = Math.floor(1000000*phi / drad) / 1000000;

  const lng = D * (1 + D*D * ((-1 -2*T1 -C1)/6 + D*D * (5 - 2*C1 + 28*T1 - 3*C1*C1 + 8*e0sq + 24*T1*T1) / 120)) / Math.cos(phi1);
  const lngd = zcm + lng/drad;

  // Output Longitude:
  const outLon = Math.floor(1000000*lngd)/1000000;

  return [outLat, outLon];
}

// This will log "[41.33544, 19.789071]" to the console.
console.log(utmToLatLon(398676.179117283, 4576702.45725602, 34, true));
```

I have published a Google Apps Script version of this function, for use in Google Sheets: https://gist.github.com/attilaolah/6cf22de8949d45a6cc06286536050e42.

Comment: This code gives very accurate result. TNX!

Comment: That works awesome. thank you bro.